# My Animation JPGs won't release

Tags: ios, animation, memory, uiimage

Ive been running my app through Instruments (Allocator) checking the memory use for my app. The majority of the app releases the memory when I exit the page however on some pages that have animations using:

```
-(IBAction)start:(id)sender
{
    animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Paddle 1.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Paddle 2.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Paddle 3.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Paddle 4.jpg"],nil];
    [animation setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
    animation.animationDuration = 2.5;
    [animation startAnimating];
}
```

the memory jumps up to about 45MB usage (The jpgs are 330kb each) and when I exit the page there is no release.

I read around and have found that ARC doesn't always work when the storyboard is getting deep so I understand that with these pages (MainView>Container>UITableView>UITabView>UIImage) that could very well be the problem.

When i exit the app, the memory drops back to 9MB and releases the images, but should the images be released when I exit the view? The app has never crashed on me or said there is a memory problem, I just don't want this to be a reason Apple rejects the app.

This is the memory usage when the app was opened (low point) when the animation was opened (The big step up)

[image]

Is this a problem that the images only release when exiting the app? if so seeing that ARC isn't automatically releasing the images when i change the view, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change every

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"Paddle 1.jpg"]
```

to

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: GetImgWithoutCaching(@"Paddle 1.jpg")]
```

and add function

```
UIImage* GetImgWithoutCaching(NSString* imgName)
{
    NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imgName ofType:nil];
    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
}
```

because imageNamed does some caching, while imageWithContentsOfFile - not.

The final code should look like this:

```
UIImage* GetImgWithoutCaching(NSString* imgName)
{
    NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imgName ofType:nil];
    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
}

-(IBAction)start:(id)sender
{
    animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 GetImgWithoutCaching(@"Paddle 1.jpg"),
                                 GetImgWithoutCaching(@"Paddle 2.jpg"),
                                 GetImgWithoutCaching(@"Paddle 3.jpg"),
                                 GetImgWithoutCaching(@"Paddle 4.jpg"),nil];
    [animation setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
    animation.animationDuration = 2.5;
    [animation startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: is that added just after the last '}'?

Comment: I am sorry, my first idea probably was wrong. Try to change imageNamed with imageWithContentsOfFile, please.

Comment: nothing would happen when i pressed play for the animation with imageWithContentsOfFile

Comment: You have to pass a full path to the file when you use `imageWithContentsOfFile:`.

Comment: Awesome!Thank you I will make sure it works in a minute. @Avt

Comment: @Avt where would the GetImgWithoutCaching function go in the code?

Comment: It could be placed in any place

Comment: @Avt ar ether changes to that code i need to make in accordance to my file names?
getting errors like
incompatible pointer types, unexpected interface name etc